# Unit (Integration) Test - ( SSH Connection, SNMP, etc) in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ssh, snmp

I am new to making Unit Tests. I just started with some for my easy classes and functionality.

But I have some problems with more complex situations.

For example:

I have an method `"ResultObject getServerStatus(string ip,string user,string pass,...)"`

and in this Method an SSH Connection is made to the server and several checks are done.

What is the right way to test (Simulate) such dependencies like "SSH Connection and interaction with SSH Shell" or stuff like "SNMP Requests"? Obviously in my test environment there are no servers  can check or SNMP devices.

What is the correct way to test such complex scenarios and can you point me to some good examples which such dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to separate the third party logic in your classes.

**Example:**

```
public class MyClass
{
    private SshMagic _sshMagic = new SshMagic(); // or something like that

    ...
    ResultObject getServerStatus(string ip,string user,string pass,...)
    {
        if (..)
        {
           return _sshMagic.Something();
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

What you want to test is the code that is yours: the conditions, the loops, etc. The `return _sshMagic.Something()` line is an external logic, you definitly don't want to test that.

## First step

Wrap SshMagic behind an interface. There will be two benefits of this:

1) you can change the implementation any time (like a new version with different API comes out, so you have to rewrite only your wrapper: all other code probably won't need a bit of change)

2) its always a good chance to create an adapter and focus on what you want to do instead of the implementation details of, for example SshMagic class. Example: if you never use 2 parameters out of four in a method, you can hide them, or you if you are calling 3 methods together, you can wrap them in one method...

**Example:**

```
public interface ISshMagic
{
    ...
    ResultObject Something();
    ...   
}

public class MyClass
{
    private ISshMagic _sshMagic;

    public MyClass(ISshMagic sshMagic)
    {
        _sshMagic = sshMagic;
    }

    ...
}
```

## Second step

Now that we have separated the dependency, we will mock the bastard. You have to select one mocking framework like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), [Simple.Mocking](http://simplemocking.codeplex.com/) etc. For the sake of example, I will use Simple.Mocking here.

**Example**

You create the MockObject here:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTesty
{
    ...
    [Test]
    public void GetServerStatus_Will_Call_Something_Of_SshMagic()
    {
        ...
        _mockSshMagic = Mock.Interface<ISshMagic>();
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(_mockSshMagic);
        ...

        // we are setting up that _mockSshMagic.Something() will be called
        Expect.Once.MethodCall(() => _mockSshMagic.Something());
        ...

        // do your test here...
        myClass.("255.255.255.0", "Me", "MyPassword", ...);
        ...

        // we are checking that our expectations were met:
        AssertInvocationsWereMade.MatchingExpectationsFor(_mockSshMagic);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thats an straight forward answer... Thank you :)

Comment: The biggest problem i have is that i must create test unit for a code that already exists (i have more than 200 seperate classes that are all doing other stuff), and now i feel the pain of not doing "test driven developement" because changing all the stuff this way for hundrets of classes is really much work :D

Comment: Well, its a common problem. Probably you can't and won't cover every class in your code, but even in that case it will add value. When you refactor or add new code, do it in TDD and the old cold base will slowly die out :).